# jQuery - calculate div width - divs does not fit on the screen (strange behavior)

Tags: jquery, width

I am using jQuery to calculate the width of the divs. For example: first I use

```
var width = $(window).width();
var cWidth = width * 0.96;
$('#parent').width(cWidth);
```

And later

```
var boxWidth = cWidth * 0.25;
$('.box').width(boxWidth);
```

my html looks

```
<div id="parent">
<div class="box">[image here]</div>
<div class="box">[image here]</div>
<div class="box">[image here]</div>
<div class="box">[image here]</div>
</div>
```

As you see I have four boxes in same line, I mean 4 divs. So when window width is 1366px it give me 4 divs of a width of 327.84px (1366 * 0.96 = 1311.36px; 1311.36px * 0.25 = 327.84px)

And it works like a charm.

http://www.wytworniaprojektu.eu/screen_1366.jpg

The problem occurs when the screen resolution is 1349px (but not only)

Then my jQuery calculations script givs me this:

cWidth = 1295.04px

so .box have width: 323.76px (1349 * 0.96 = 1295.04px; 1295.04 * 0.25 = 323.76px)

Its should fit together, but one of them go to the next line:

http://www.wytworniaprojektu.eu/screen_1349.jpg

I don't understand what's going wrong? Math calculation it's correct, so it looks at the problem with decimal part?

Any idea?

Comment: httP://www.wytworniaprojektu.eu/#wok - you can see it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give a decimal pixels to browsers, they has to make st. with this number, because they are able to show only pixels, not their parts.

And there is difference between browser, some of them round decimal pixels, some floor pixels, maybe ceil pixels.

And this is the point, if they ceil or round pixels up (the same when ou have XX.84), the total width will be `parent.width() + 1` (or more) > the last one `.box` has no space and goe to the second line.

Possible solution: add one more wrapper, JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H97Ay/.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. To ensure they fit, floor the result of your multiplication of `0.25`:

   ```
   var boxWidth = Math.floor(cWidth * 0.25);
   ```

   That way, you won't have fractions adding up oddly. What browsers do with fractional pixel values may not be what you expect them to do, so I would generally avoid them. (I'd probably also either round or floor your overall width for the parent so you get a whole number.)
2. I'd also remove the whitespace between the divs, since that whitespace will have non-zero width:

   ```
   <div id="parent"><div class="box">[image here]</div><div class="box">[image here]</div><div class="box">[image here]</div><div class="box">[image here]</div></div>
   ```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/nukefafa/1) (resizes when you resize the window). *(I assume the `.box` divs have `display: inline-block` or similar.)*